# Rotating Parent View Controller, if Presenting a viewController from NavigationController

Tags: ios

I am using a `NavigationController` in my app and from there, I present a `viewController` like a popup. So if I rotate the device, I am able to rotate the topView(Presented `viewController`) but unable to rotate the parent view controller which is on top of the navigation controller.

I need guidance on why is this occurring and how to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

If your parent view controller(Presenting view controller) is not a visible view controller, then rotation methods(`- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation`) are never called in parent view controller (Presenting view controller). So you should explicitly rotate your view controller based on the status bar orientation. However **viewWillLayoutSubviews** method will called in your parent view controller when you dismiss your presented view controller. Do the stuff there...

**In your parent view controller:**

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews 
{
    //Check your your view controller is visible. If not visible then call
    [self willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] duration:0];
}
```